# Passing a pointer to one derived class to another

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I'm still learning basics of c++, but I'm currently working on a project using derived classes and virtual methods. So the situation is:
I have a ClassA

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    virtual void action();
};
```

And there are two derived classes B and C:

```
#include "ClassA.h" 

class ClassB: public ClassA
{
public:
    virtual void action();
    int valueB;
};
```

-

```
#include "ClassA.h"

class ClassC: public ClassA
{
public:
    virtual void action();
    int valueC;
};
```

I want to pass a pointer to an object of ClassB as a parameter of action() in ClassC, so I can do something like this:

```
void ClassC::action(ClassB * ptr)
{
cout << "The value is: " << ptr->valueB;
}
```

However I cannot find a working way to do it. All of the object pointers are stored in a

```
vector<ClassA *> objects
```

where

```
objects[0]=new ClassC();
objects[1]=new ClassB();
```

if I try something like

```
objects[0]->action(object[1])
```

then I need my virtual method in ClassA to have a parameter ClassB *. And then for a program to recognise the type I tried either including entire ClassB.h (bad idea, it creates a "loop" of includes or something) or using a forward declaration class ClassB; (I get an error about invalid use of incomplete type). And so I'm currently stuck. I hope that everything is clear, but I can of course provide more datails if needed.

Comment: Right. because it would be unsafe to blindly downcast an `A*` to a `B*`

Comment: what about getting rid of valueB and valueC and just have an int value; in ClassA?

Comment: You would use the forward declaration of class ClassB in the header of another class and the include in cpp-File. Together with the Sentinel, as described down, it will avoid the loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to forward declare something it is because you can't include the whole definition of the class. In this situation if you forward declare `ClassB` the compiler doesn't know about its member attribute `valueB`, that's why you get an incomplete type error. To solve this problem you have to factor code something like:

```
//ClassA.h
class ClassB;

class ClassA
{
  virtual void action(ClassB* ptr);
}

//ClassA.cpp
#include "ClassB.h"
void ClassA::action(ClassB* ptr) { ... }
```

So you are basically using the header to declare the virtual method and forward declare `ClassB`, but you define it in `ClassA.cpp`, so that in the source file you can include `ClassB.h` with no problems and no risks of circular dependencies.

Comment: I just tested this solution and it works really well. The only difference is that I included ClassB.h in ClassC.cpp instead of ClassA.cpp. Your solution resulted in the same error (incomplete type). I'm not sure why, but could it be because ClassC.h has ClassA.h included (where the forward declaration is) but has no knowledge about ClassA.cpp (where the actual definitione is)?

Answer (score 1):

I notice your ClassC virtual function is declared as taking no parameters:

```
virtual void action();
```

but you define your derived class function with a parameter.

```
void ClassC::action(ClassB * ptr)
```

The declaration and definition must match. Change the declaration to:

```
virtual void action(ClassB *);
```

Hmm. But then you must either include ClassB before the ClassC declaration...

```
#include "ClassB.h"
```

or forward declare ClassB. This is a promise to the compiler to properly declare and define the class later. A good place to insert this line would be just before the ClassC declaration.

```
class ClassB;
```

Comment: The answer is not bad. But, how should the reader know where to insert the forward declaration? Please take into account, that the OP still learns the basics of C++.

Comment: Edited to suggest a place to put the forward declaration. Thanks for the assistance. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could define `action` (in all classes) as:

```
virtual void action(ClassA * ptr); // or ClassB *
```

Then you can pass any instance of ClassA or derived from ClassA.
All derived classes can include ClassA with `#include "ClassA.h"`, if you provide the Sentinel in the header-File as it is common in c++ :

```
#ifndef ClassAH
#define ClassAH

...

#endif
```

So, the header will be included only once...

Comment: Not sure, but I think the OP requested a parameter of type `ClassB *`.

Comment: You edited it in between. `ClassB *` cannot be used in the parameter list without a forward declaration.

Comment: You are right. If you want to use ClassB, you would use the forward declaration of class ClassB in the header of another class and the include in cpp-File. Together with the Sentinel it will avoid the loop.